# Write text inside rectangle

Tags: html, rectangles

I am trying to find how to filltext inside a rectangle. Unfortunately i can only find C# projects/tutorials.
Is it possible to add text inside a rectangle in HTML5 in a canvas?
I want each rectangle (node) to have a different text on it for example 1 is called cow and the other tiger and so on. Is this possible? i have tried everything!

```js
var x = 150;
var y = 100;

var canvas = $('#NodeList').get(0);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "30px Arial";

canvas.height = 0;

var rects = [
    [20, 20, x, y],
    [20, 220, x, y],
    [20, 420, x, y],
    [20, 620, x, y],
    [20, 820, x, y],
    [20, 1020, x, y],
    [20, 1220, x, y],
    [20, 1420, x, y],
    [20, 1620, x, y]
];

for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    canvas.height = canvas.height + 200;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // redraw rectangles
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        ctx.fillRect(rects[j][0],
        rects[j][1],
        rects[j][2],
        rects[j][3]);
    }
    ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
    rects[i][1],
    rects[i][2],
    rects[i][3]);
}

$('#NodeList').click(function (e) {
    var x = e.offsetX,
        y = e.offsetY;

    for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        if (x > rects[i][0] &&
            x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2] &&
            y > rects[i][1] &&
            y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]
         ) {
            alert('Vierkant ' + i + ' clicked');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its really old question. But I ran into a similar so I decided to post the answer.

**Note**: You have to treat `canvas` differently that `html` tags like `div`. You get one `ctx` for `canvas` and you paint on it like a stream. Just change the position of your next elements and it would as expected.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();


context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.shadowColor = '#999';
context.shadowBlur = 20;
context.shadowOffsetX = 15;
context.shadowOffsetY = 15;
context.fill();
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.font = '20px Courier';
context.shadowColor = 'transparent';
context.shadowBlur = 0;
context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
context.fillText(`List item`, 200, 80);

context.lineWidth = 7;
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```